# Failed to define class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader in Module java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss

```html
<context:annotation-config />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.lv.rs.accessautomation.view.controller" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>
 <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />
 <mvc:resources location="/style/style.css" mapping="/style/**" />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />


 <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" /> -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
        
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@sam123:1521:sam123" /> 
        <property name="user" value="sample"/> 
        <property name="password" value="Pass1234"/> 
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/> 
    </bean>


 <bean id="ressessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource">
   <ref bean="dataSource" />
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <!-- <prop key="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:jboss/OracleDS/RESGlobaldata</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
    <prop key="connection.pool_size">1</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> -->


       <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</prop> 
     
     <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">resources</prop> 
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop> 
     <prop key="connection.pool_size">1</prop> 
     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
     <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> 
   </props>
  </property>
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>com.sample.pvo</value>
    <value>com.sample.rsvo</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>
 
    <tx:annotation-driven />
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="ressessionFactory"></property>
 </bean>
```

Iam getting the below exception if i deploy the war[spring +Hibernate applicatiob] in jboss server.
Iam getting this error agter making Database call. Is it due to session is not properly closed ? will spring servlet.xml won't take care of it ?

```html
18:47:05,404 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class org.springframework.expression.Expression in Module "deployment.RSAccessMgmt.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]

18:47:08,436 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."RSAccessMgmt.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."RSAccessMgmt.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "RSAccessMgmt.war"
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.RSAccessMgmt.war:main" from Service Module Loader
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/expression/Expression;
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 ... 10 more
```

Comment: show eclipse.ini file and what value is there for `XXMaxPermSize`

Comment: whats ini file. form where i can get that file ?

Comment: -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m